# Aligning iframes side by side in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have two iframes on a wordpress site using the twenty thirteen theme and can't get them to be aligned next to each other! they seem to be stacked vertically and this happens with other elements also! here is the html for the iframes..

```html
<iframe src="myfirstframe" width="290" height="375" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>


<iframe src="mysecondframe" height="470" width="640" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I have tried divs and floating left in css in wordpress to no avail
here is the current css in wordpress....

```css
#page {
      width: 1060px;
}

#content {
     width:  620px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a container. And use the css below

```
<div class="iframe-cont">
<iframe src="myfirstframe" width="290" height="375" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>


<iframe src="mysecondframe" height="470" width="640" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>


.iframe-cont {
  display: flex;
}
```

You can change their width and height with this

```
    .iframe-cont > iframe {
      height: ;
      width: ;
/**display: inline-block;**/
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean wrap in a div container i.e <div class="iframe-con"t>

Comment: Getting there! only i need them to keep there current width and heights! when i use the code you suggest they are the same width/height, when i change one it affects the other iframe

Comment: I suggested but you don't need to change it if you need it that way

Answer (score 0):

Is your page wide enough? Look at this snippet, works as planned - otherwise you probably have some other css causing issues

```css
iframe {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="#" width="20" height="60" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="#" height="60" width="40" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: That just puts a red border aroudn the iframes! they still remained stacked on each other

Comment: They're side by side for me